# How do I find the memory and time required for modeling/checking the satisfiability in Z3 (NET API)

Tags: z3

I am working with Z3 and Yices for less than a year for solving some research problems. Working with these solvers, I always need to evaluate the performance, especially two things: time and space (memory) required for modeling/checking (the satisfiability). In case of Z3, I found no clue to find them directly. I tried with the "statistics" (using the function "DisplayStatistics" provided by Z3 NET API), and found the output as shown (e.g.) below:

> num. conflicts:     122
>
> num. decisions:     2245
>
> num. propagations:  27884 (binary: 21129)
>
> num. restarts:      1
>
> num. final checks:  1
>
> num. min. lits:     52
>
> num. added eqs.:    3766
>
> num. mk bool var:   2782
>
> num. del bool var:  658
>
> num. mk enode:      1723
>
> num. del enode:     78
>
> num. mk clause:     3622
>
> num. del clause:    1517
>
> num. mk bin clause: 3067
>
> num. mk lits:       18935
>
> num. ta conflicts:  28
>
> num. add rows:      5091
>
> num. pivots:        328
>
> num. assert lower:  2597
>
> num. assert upper:  3416
>
> num. assert diseq:  1353
>
> num. bound prop:    787
>
> num. fixed eqs:     697
>
> num. offset eqs:    866
>
> num. pseudo nl.:    34
>
> num. eq. adapter:   820

I do not know how to interpret these values to understand the used memory/time. There is some way to find the running time (using timer classes like Stopwatch). But, in case of space requirement, I did not find any way. If I can get the number of Boolean variables (low level, SAT solver) required for modeling could work very well for me.

It would be great, if anyone can show me the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Z3 are you using? The latest version (Z3 3.2) includes memory consumption statistics. It will be displayed as `max. heap size`. That being said, the best way to evaluate Z3's performance is to use `z3.exe`. The Z3 executable will report time and memory consumption. Moreover, some performance improvements are not yet available through the API.

For several applications the textual interface is the ideal option. That is, your application communicates with the Z3 process using SMT 2.0 commands through a pipe. The main advantages are: it is very easy to use different SMT solvers and compare them; it is easy to kill Z3 and restart it; you can create several different processes; if Z3 dies your application does not die. Of course, this solution is not good for applications that perform thousands of easy queries, or require a tight integration with Z3 (e.g. `Scala^Z3`).

Comment: Thank you. I have a different issue. I am wondering about the MAXSAT functionality in Z3 (especially in Z3 NET API). I found that I need to implement such functionality (as shown in the C API examples). In case of Yices, there is built-in functions (e.g., yices_max_sat), which works according to the weighted assertions (using yices_assert_weighted). Can Z3 provide such an easy way to use MAXSAT using NET API?

Comment: I implemented the `yices_max_sat` command using `assumptions`. The command `yices_assert_weighted` just creates a `hidden` Boolean variable (i.e., an assumption variable) and associates the weight to it. So, these two commands can be simulated on top of the Z3 API using `assumptions`. There are many ways to implement MAXSAT on top of the Z3 API. The `maxsat.c` example describes two of them. We have no plans to support MAXSAT in the official API. That being said, in future releases, we may include a .NET version of `maxsat.c`.

Comment: Thanks. The .NET version of maxsat.c would be great helpful for me. I wish we will get it very soon. However, how the weight can be set is not clear to me from the maxsat.c example.

Comment: Z3 (SMT-LIB) does not support MAXSAT like yices (i.e., the 'max-sat' command in SMT-LIB). Code for MAXSAT is given for C API. Can Z3 provide similar functionality like yices (both) in SMTLIB (and API)?

Comment: Yes, we do not support the maxsat command, and there are no plans to support it in the near future. As I said in the previous comments, You can simulate it using `assumptions`. That is how I implemented it in Yices.

Comment: I am using z3 4.4 and I didn't see anything about memory usage in solver.statistics(). Is "max heap memory" stat provided in z3.py?